# Managing common SQL code in postgres database via liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

We are using [SQL formatted changelogs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html). We have a sql file, `create_db.sql` for each postgres database managed via liquibase. We have few common tables for each database which is placed in a `common.sql` file.

It looks like [include](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/include.html) element can serve my purpose. But it does not work with SQL formatted changelogs.

One approach I can think of handling this case is to not have common.sql altogether and place all the common code in each `create_db.sql` as I could not find any way of importing `common.sql` in each `create_db.sql` to be managed via liquibase using sql formatted changelogs. But this will cause a lot of code duplication.

Can someone suggest some other better way of managing the `common.sql` file also via liquibase for each postgres database?

Comment: what would you like to achieve? Can you use also other types than formatted sql from which you would be able to include those formatted sqls? What about using [context](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/contexts.html) - it could be used for some kind of separation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the below statement in the [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/include.html).

> At this time, the  tag cannot be used in an SQL formatted
> root changelog.

Only root changelog cannot be SQL formatted but `<include>` does work with SQL formatted changelogs as explained by the below statement

> Your reference changelog can be SQL, XML, YAML, or JSON file types.

The example in the documentation also shows the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-latest.xsd">
    <include file="com/example/news/news.changelog.sql"/>
    <include file="com/example/directory/directory.changelog.sql"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```